# Facebook like button plugin - show specific number of faces

Tags: facebook, social-networking, facebook-likebox

Is there any way to show limited profile faces on Facebook like box plugin?

Say I just want to show 5 profile faces?

I am using the HTML version of Facebook's like box i.e. I user `data-show-faces="true"`

Answer (score 4):

The only way to change the number of faces is by setting a height on the like-box plugin.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

```
Take the following height examples:

250px or less, you get 5 faces,
251px-303px is 10 faces.
304px-356px is 15 faces
357px-409px is 20 faces

And so on in multiples of 53px = 5 additional faces.
```

Comment: So why the hell am I getting 11 faces with a div sized 300 by 230? One of which ends up at the bottom half hidden... :( started behaving like this as of recently!

Comment: The figures I give above are still correct as of right now. Click the link above to see them in action. Keep in mind this is with the 'Show Header' option checked. With it unchecked, you need to adjust the figures down by 30px.
As to why yours is showing 11 with those measurements, I don't know. Try going to the link above, regenerating, and replacing your existing code. Yours may be old or out of date and have been broken by one of Facebook's silent updates.

Comment: Thanks, yes most probably broken by one of their updates. It used to work fine and show just 10 faces. Its actually using their own Wordpress Facebook plugin! You can see it here: http://www.eve.com.mt :(

Comment: Weird - it's displaying fine on that site for me. 10 faces (2 rows of 5).

Comment: Inspecting the elements I noted that there is a hidden face when I am logged in, which is mine - it appears before the other faces, but has display:none !important; on the .pluginFacepileConnectFirst class. If I adjust this to actually display my face, it pushes the others out and cuts off the last one, but this shouldn't be happening by default. Curious as to whether the first face in the pile is your account though.

Comment: Yes, its my face! Maybe its because I 'liked' that page though? Did you try clicking Like to see if it shows it? In my case the CSS I see is `display: inline-block !important;`

Comment: Actually it seems like a new bug they've introduced recently. Someone actually filed it: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/223956607795977/

Comment: Yep, you're correct. Good job on finding this bug! Have verified it on my own sites too.

Comment: Cheers... at least I know I am not crazy :)... lets hope they don't take long to fix it

Comment: They just fixed it. Its working fine now. https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/223956607795977/

Answer (score 1):

No, the only options for the 'show_faces' parameter of the [Like Button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) are true and false

Answer (score 0):

No, you can´t limit the number of faces displayed in the widget. You have all the information here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/